# podman machine init debian

Tags: debian, podman

Following up on [How to install docker-engine in macOS without docker desktop?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/667940/how-to-install-docker-engine-in-macos-without-docker-desktop), which mentioned that `podman machine init`

> set a machine with Fedora CoreOS by default.

Yet I want to prepare a Debian machine, and when I tried:

```
$ podman machine init debian
Extracting compressed file: debian_fedora-coreos-39.20231204.2.1-qemu.aarch64.q…
Image resized.
Machine init complete
To start your machine run:

    podman machine start debian
```

The output just doesn't looks right.

Is the prepared VM Debian or Fedora CoreOS?

How to prepare a Debian VM (`debian:stable-backport` as per `docker`) with `podman` please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`podman machine init debian` doesn’t create a Debian-based VM, it creates a Fedora CoreOS VM *named* `debian`. That’s why the output references Fedora CoreOS. The argument to [`podman machine init`](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-machine-init.1.html) is the machine’s name (defaulting to `podman-machine-default`).

I’m not sure Podman can use a Debian-based VM; in particular, the version of Podman inside the VM needs to match the version run outside, so if a Debian VM can be made to work, it would have to track Debian testing (the Podman package isn’t backported).

Since you’re apparently looking to run a Debian *container*, you don’t need to worry about the VM;

```
podman run -it debian:stable-backports
```

will run a Debian “stable with backports” container and attach to it.

Comment: @xpt note that your question actually was "*Is the prepared VM Debian or Fedora CoreOS?*" and Stephen answered that with "it's a CoreOS"! I'd still be curious why you want debian for the VM – that seems surprising to me! It might really be helpful to tell us why!

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I automate setting up my entire VM using a script and it is entirely written for Debian.

Comment: OK, good question, as this is the first time I'm trying to use podman, and all I want is a Debian container, like what I used to do with `docker run debian`. If you think it is possible please provide your answer in details how I can do it. thanks @MarcusMüller.

Comment: I’ve added that to the answer.

Comment: @xpt if you’re working with containers, instead of setting up environments with a script, you might find it more useful to write a `Containerfile` — that would allow you to build your image once and re-use it without needing any changes (until you need to update it, *e.g.* to fix security issues).